# Use and manage one theme on multiple wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress

I managed multiple wordpress sites. One of my clients has a number of small onepage sites who are using the same base theme.

Because I'm working on this theme on a regular base and want to update al the site using it, I was wondering if there's a way to use a theme from one location/ different domain so I only have to update the theme one time instead of every single site.

Ive tried tools like ManageWP, they actually work pretty nice, but it needs an extra plugin (which cannot be updated within this tool).

I could think of something like a wordpress function which says: insert url of theme folder.

Anyone think this is possible?

Thanks.